# pgfplots, z range in a logarithmic heatmap

Tags: pgfplots

Changing the z range in a heatmap it with `zmin`,`zmax` either does nothing (see the image below) or produces a message `You have an axis with empty range (in direction y). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots.` **How to set the z range in a logarithmic heatmap?**

```
\begin{filecontents}{map.txt}
    0.1 0   2.933100901655603E-6
    0.1 10  1.2378929491530841E-5
    0.1 20  2.0588051604902755E-5
    0.1 30  2.7190941686966532E-5
    0.1 40  3.290721897852047E-5
    0.1 60  4.250275971734089E-5
    0.1 80  5.0350197981567186E-5
    0.1 100 5.681643648591518E-5
    0.1 150 6.859558257512272E-5
    0.1 200 7.652271637806553E-5
    0.1 250 8.22752949739641E-5
    0.1 300 8.668070617985642E-5

    0.2 0   1.362157048411715E-5
    0.2 10  1.4186557576426701E-5
    0.2 20  1.9510106350903664E-5
    0.2 30  2.3880991840192088E-5
    0.2 40  2.7472817836855655E-5
    0.2 60  3.282892845070262E-5
    0.2 80  3.656164586607819E-5
    0.2 100 3.944614546159667E-5
    0.2 150 4.434691145348564E-5
    0.2 200 4.730750444203243E-5
    0.2 250 4.9180711846180925E-5
    0.2 300 5.0512424521156164E-5
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        zmin=-10,zmax=10,
        view={0}{90},
        colormap/jet,
        colorbar,
        colorbar style={yticklabel=$10^{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},
    ]
        \addplot3 [
            surf,
            shader=interp,
        ] table [
            x index=0,
            y index=1,
            z expr=log10(\thisrowno{2}),
        ] {map.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think `zmax` and `zmin` is for 3D-plots but you  are projecting along the z-axis so every change you made cannot be seen. What kind of effect you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the colour scale to span between the given min and max. Currently its range is equal to that of the data.

Comment: Manual p232: **This transformation depends on the interval [m_min,m_max] which, in turn, can be modified using the keys `point meta rel`, `point meta min` and `point meta max` described below.** Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes, thanks. It makes sense given that it is really a cast of a 3d mesh.